# SkyDrive backup/restore behaves strangely with different App IDs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I need some help with an issue I can't seem to figure out myself. I built an app for Windows Phone 8 that supports backup to SkyDrive of certain documents (sdf file and images). Backing up to SkyDrive and restoring to the same app (e.g. after a reinstall or deleting of items) works just fine, no problems.

The problem presented itself when my app became certified and I tried to restore the documents from SkyDrive (that were created by my debug version of the app) to the newly downloaded (from the store) published app. The restore seems to work fine, but when I refresh my list, none of the images are visible!

Comment: Do you grant full SkyDrive access to the app or just a part (a folder)?

Comment: I authenticate using the **wl.skydrive_update** scope, but only use one specific folder

Comment: Never mind, figured it out myself. Stupid, stupid, stupid!

Comment: Images were being populated using a stored path in the db, which included the APP ID.